# TypeError in React, how do I fix it so that the output is rendered correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying to follow this tutorial on how to consume a REST API in React (the tutorial uses BootStrap):

https://pusher.com/tutorials/consume-restful-api-react

I am running into an issue that I'm sure is an easy fix but I'm relatively new to JavaScript and React in general. I am trying to display the output of JSON that I am consuming from my REST API (in Django). I have tested the API and it works but I am sure the problem is with the frontend.

How can I fix this code to display the output of the REST API in the format given?

The current code gives me a `TypeError`

**TypeError**

```
TypeError: blog is undefined
Blog
src/components/blog.js:6

  3 | const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
  4 |   return (
  5 |     <div>
> 6 |       <center><h1>Blog Post</h1></center>
    | ^  7 |       {blog.map((blg) => (
  8 |         <div class="card">
  9 |           <div class="card-body">
```

**Expected output in a HTML page**

```
Blog Post
New blog post to test
Test post
RP
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Blog from './components/blog';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    blogdata: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/v1/blog/1/')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ blogdata: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }


  render () {
    return (
      <Blog blogdata={this.state.blogdata} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**/src/components/blog.js**

```
import React from 'react'

    const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <center><h1>Blog Post</h1></center>
          {blog.map((blg) => (
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{blg.title}</h5>
                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{blg.content}</h6>
                <p class="card-text">{blg.author}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default Blog
```

**JSON Post Detail at http://localhost:8000/v1/blog/1/**

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "New blog post to test",
    "content": "Test post",
    "created_at": "2020-05-11T05:41:43.213782Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-05-11T05:41:43.213951Z",
    "author": "RP"
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show right after you make the `API` call and get a response inside the `then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Change:** as props name is being mismatched

Change :

```
const Blog = ({ blog }) => {
```

To :

```
const Blog = ({ blogdata }) => {
```

---

**Second Change :** you are not getting array of blogs but a single blog, so once you solve above error you will get the error for this :) , you can solve it by

Change this :

```
{blogdata.map((blg) => ( //<---- REMOVE
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{blg.title}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{blg.content}</h6>
    <p class="card-text">{blg.author}</p>
    </div>
</div>
))} //<--- REMOVE
```

To :

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{blogdata.title}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{blogdata.content}</h6>
    <p class="card-text">{blogdata.author}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. I think your answer and Harish's answer fixed my issue. My JSON isn't being displayed but I get the following error in the console log now:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/v1/blog/1/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`

I guess this is a separate issue, isn' it?

Comment: @RahulP, yes its cross origin error, you can solve it via chrome extension,this happens when you hit apis from one domain to another.

Comment: Thank you. A question about the second change you proposed, you're saying that I shouldn't use `return`?

Comment: No, you are not getting array from `http://localhost:8000/v1/blog/1/`, its a JSON, so you can't loop through it, get it?

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer solved my issue and I finally got the values in JSON to display, however, I find an additional `)}` being printed? Is there any thing else that I am messing up on?

Comment: @RahulP, Great I don't think so . `)}` this might be of closing of for loop

Answer (score 1):

In `Blog` component you are receiving `blog` as prop and while using you are passing `blogdata`

there are 2 ways

1) Update your `app.js`

```
 render () {
    return (
      <Blog blog={this.state.blogdata} />
    );
  }
```

2) update `Blog.js`

```
import React from 'react'

const Blog = ({ blogdata}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <center><h1>Blog Post</h1></center>
      {blogdata.map((blg) => (
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{blg.title}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{blg.content}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{blg.author}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};

export default Blog
```

Comment: Thanks. This managed to display the header but the values from the JSON are not being displayed. I see this issue in the console. 

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/v1/blog/1/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`

Answer (score 1):

Other than above two answers,

Make sure to add key property to JSX item in loop, otherwise you will get another error/warning.

Copying from @Harish's answer,

```
{blogdata.map((blg, key) => (
        <div class="card" key={key}>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{blg.title}</h5>
            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{blg.content}</h6>
            <p class="card-text">{blg.author}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
```

Also, `class` shoudl be `className`